# How do I create an example reference list within the Data Tab of the Baqend Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dummy-data, baqend

In my Baqend-hosted application, I have created a "Family" Class, with some modeling attributes and a list of User references.

Now I want to add some dummy data using the Data tab in the Baqend dashboard. How do I add Users to a List of User within the Dashboard?

I have tried:
`[/db/User/id, /db/User/id]`
`[username, username]`
`username, username`
`<username>,<username>`
`<id>,<id>` 
`/db/user/<id>` 
etc

But the frame stays red, suggesting invalid data.

Comment: Disclaimer: This question was asked and answered in the support chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Tab of the dashboard expects for a field of the type `List<ref>` a JSON Array of String values.

The reference has to be the full object reference.
Your first try was nearly correct, just add quotation marks.

```
["/db/User/id", "/db/User/id"]
```

Comment: If this solved your problem you should mark your answer as "accepted", so the system knows that the question has been resolved. It is perfectly acceptable to accept your own answers.